# Flutter Firebase Auth reurn wrong errror message

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

firebase_auth: 4.12.1

```
 try { 
    await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email: email.text, password: pass.text); } 
    on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) { 
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {} 
    else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') 
    { toast("Wrong password provided for that user."); }
     else { toast(e.toString()); }
```

> when try to used the email which is not register yet it still give
> error Invalid credentials instead it should give error code
> user-not-found and also when i use email tha is register with wrong
> password i give Invalid credentials error code instead it should give
> wrong-password

Comment: add your definition inside the if statement, if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {}, you have not added anything inside the if statement.